# d3 selectAll is not a function with Vue and AudioContext

Tags: audio, d3.js

I have an vue.js app with html5 audio code (to track AudioContext). The funny thing is that it works without Vue (with exactly the same code)

**Simplified vue code**

```
// import stuff

let player = new Vue({
  data: function() {
    return {
      audio: null,
      analyser: null,
      frequencyData: null,
      svg: null,
      currentTrack: data
    }
  },

  methods: {
    initAllTracks: function() {
      // ...
      this.initPlayer();
    },

    initPlayer: function() {
      this.audio = new Audio('audio_source_link');
      this.audio.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

      this.startPlaying();
    },

    startPlaying: function() {
      // ...
      this.initAudioContext();
    },

    initAudioContext: function() {
      let audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
      let audioSrc = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(this.audio);
      this.analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();

      audioSrc.connect(this.analyser);
      audioSrc.connect(audioCtx.destination);

      this.audio.play();

      this.frequencyData = new Uint8Array(5);
      this.svg = d3.select('.app').append('svg');

      this.renderSVG();
    },

    renderSVG: function() {
      requestAnimationFrame(this.renderSVG);

      console.log('FIRST: ' , this.frequencyData);

      this.analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 1 - (4 / 100);
      this.analyser.getByteFrequencyData(this.frequencyData);

      console.log('SECOND: ' , this.frequencyData);

      var radiusScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(this.frequencyData)]).range([0, 1200 / 2]);
      var circles = this.svg.selectAll('circle').data(this.frequencyData);

      circles.enter().append('circle');

      circles
        .attr({
          // ...
        });

      circles.exit().remove();
    }
  }
});
```

I call `initAllTracks()` and the app starts.

But, on the code line `var circles = this.svg.selectAll('circle').data(this.frequencyData);` i become the error `TypeError: this.svg.selectAll is not a function`.

The console.log gives me an correct `Uint8Array`. Then i tried to remove `this.frequencyData` (maybe there is an problem with the binding from vue.js) and make it global. But nothing changes...

Here is again the funny thing: If i write all this code without Vue.js (just defining all variable on the start and write the functions down). And this works...

// EDIT:

I put the `renderSVG` function INTO the `initAudioContext` function, and it works..why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
this.svg = d3.select('.app').append('svg');
```

Don't set vue data to the d3 instance, cause vue data will change d3 instance prototype.

Try assign that to a standalone variable.